# Connection String on a Shared Host Server

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, connection-string, shared-hosting

I am trying to figure out if I have done something wrong.  I have an MVC5 EF6 Project.  I have placed it inside the public_html folder on my shared host server.   I have created a MySQL Database and added a user for it.  I have made sure to have the MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll and MySql.Data.dll included and referenced in the project.

I have the following connection string in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=s023.someserver.com;UserId=shost_admin;Password=1Ycdcamj71Zh;database=shost_MySite;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tried few things, I removed the charset and Persist Security Info lines and it still doesn't work.  The server portion I was not 100% sure where to get from so I got it from the PHP my admin by running the following query:

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'`

Locally I used SQL Server Database to test and that works fine without a hitch.  The connection string name is the same so I know it is trying to hit the right connection string, but I feel that I have it missconfigured.

The error message that I get every time is:

> An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.

EDIT:

Found the problem, I had to also specify the port and the entitiyframework section in web.config.

Full answer here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: _The server portion I was not 100% sure where to get from so I got it from the PHP_ - how do you know Sql server is installed on the same machine?

Comment: @Pawel I don't, it is weekend and I can't get in touch with the people who set this server up, but this is the only time I'll have to get it all setup for the client.  The CPanel had no options to tell me this information, at least I did not see any.  So I thought I would try getting it from the server variables and try my luck.

Comment: first of all i want to say ... i hope you didn't use the real user name and password. if so don't forget to change it.

Comment: @Bagzil - If you don't know what server the database is installed on there is no point asking this question. How anyone on stackoverflow is supposed to know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the connection string did not specify port.